# Html5 canvas dragging and moving image with rotation

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm trying to get and image on canvas to move, scale and rotate at the same time. Everything else works fine except combining rotation + scaling with moving. User can move the image by dragging and it works fine if the image is not rotated.

Here's the function:

```
function draw() {
    t.reset();
    ctx.setTransform(t.m[0], t.m[1], t.m[2], t.m[3], t.m[4], t.m[5]);
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    t.scale(scaleAmt, scaleAmt);
    t.rotate(rotAmt);
    t.translate(movX, movY);
    ctx.setTransform(t.m[0], t.m[1], t.m[2], t.m[3], t.m[4], t.m[5]);
    ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0);
}
```

EDIT (what it excactly does wrong): If i have the image rotated 0° the image will move fine. However, if the image is not in 0° angle, the image will move like it was still in 0° angle (if i move my cursor up, image will move up from it's top = 0y)

Comment: Please clarify how your code is misbehaving--what's it doing wrong?

Comment: Can you also clarify what type of object `t` is exactly?